# General approach for dry run of building a firmware

Tags: compilation

Static code analysis tools often watch the build process by inserting their own tool which then runs the normal build process.

Thus the compiling output in the console can be monitored by the specific tool.

Is there a simple, general way to run the compilation process without real compiling. Meaning, not a dedicated solution depending on a specific compiler but a general trick.

The idea would be to reduce the compilation time as only the output is relevant.

Remarks are welcome.

Monica

Comment: Your question, in addition to sounding too broad to me, seems rather flawed.  There are plenty of static analysis tools which don't require compiling (e.g. lint or pretty much anything that has lint in the name).  The main advantage of inserting itself into the compile change is that there's a strong overlap between what a compiler needs to do to convert stuff into the next steps and what a static analysis tool would need (e.g. building parse trees).  I suggest providing a specific example of a tool-chain that is problematic instead of this overly broad topic.

Comment: Also (and probably off topic for firmware), there are Java static analysis tools which need the code to be compiled because they work off the Java byte code and not the Java source, which has the added benefit that they can work (at least somewhat) with anything that compiles to Java byte code [e.g. Jython, Jruby, Scala, etc.] as opposed to just Java.  I believe there are .NET tools that work the same way (at least for VB.net vs C#]

Comment: @Foon The question is not how a static code analysis tool works but how I can compile a SW without generating the object files. For me the only interesting point is what sources would be compiled, which include paths are given, which defines are set. As there are so many compilers and sca tools outside I am interested in a general trick - which I am not aware of.
But to be more precise: I use Klocwork for sca and here Klocwork uses the approach to monitor the build. The build takes time. If I could only simulate that compile Klocwork would get the data it needs and the process could be faster.